# Find a bounded non-constant harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a bit lost on an exercise. The question is as follows:

**Find an example of a non-constant harmonic function, $u(z)$, in $\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid \Im>0\}$, that is both upper and lower bounded.**

Due to Liouville's theorem, I know that the function can't be entire. Other than that, I have no idea what else to consider. Therefore any inputs are much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
 u(z) = \arg(z) \quad (0 < \arg(z) < \pi)
$$
(the principal value of the argument) is harmonic in the upper half-plane because it is the imaginary part of the (principal value of the) logarithm.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, $u$ is harmonic because the principal logarithm is holomorphic (in $\mathbb{C}_\pi$) right?

Comment: @limeeattack: I don't know what $\mathbb{C}_\pi$ is, but the principal value of the logarithm is holomorphic in the plane without the negative real axis.

Comment: By $\mathbb{C}_{\pi}$ I mean the cut plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{z\in \mathbb{R}\mid z\leq 0\}$. So exactly what you stated. Thank you for your time and help :D